# Installing app through GPO

Tags: windows, windows-7, group-policy, ping

I will need your help... The last day i set up an app to be installed using GPO under computer configuration.

The most of our computers are using WIFI to log in to our domain. Some of them, they received the .msi file and installed it without any issue.
But some of the, could not install it... From GPO i tried to increase the "Startup Policy Processing wait time" (Computer Configuration > Policies > Admin Templates > System > Group Policy) to 30sec, 60sec, 120sec, but nothing... 
Also, in our Default Domain Policy i have enabled the "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon".

After testing i found out the following:

In the computer that the app was installed successfully, i ping it from another pc during rebooting. When this pc was in CTL+ALT+DEL, i can ping it.

I did the same in a laptop which the app was not installed and when this pc was in CTL+ALT+DEL, i can not ping it... I can ping it only when a user logs in!!

I believe that this is the issue. Do you know why this happens? How can i solve it?

Thank you

PS: All computers have Windows 7 and our DC Servers have Windows 2016 R2

Comment: What do the event logs of the affected computers show abput this?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is a third-party wireless utility managing the adapter but not running as a service.

Typically these utilities have an option to "Let Windows manage the wireless" or "Run as a service". Either one may resolve the problem.

Generally, you're better off installing the wireless driver only and using Windows to manage the adapters if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Both laptop are using the save drivers and same WIFI utility. I will try to find how to run the utility Run as a service.